# Dynamically creating an ng-switch inside a directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a new directive that selects among several children using an ng-switch. This example is not much more than creating an ng-switch inside a directive, but eventually the directive will have more display sugar and some automatic functions so it seemed that creating a directive was the right solution.

My progress so far is in this plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yeCiIOCQswYJHyTozQUZ

The $compile I'm doing seems to be evaluating the switch, and determining that the value doesn't match any of the when clauses which shouldn't be true. You can see that by inspecting the elements in the rendered picker.

I'm also concerned that calling $compile at this stage seems to have thrown away the item list, so it seems like I'm barking up the wrong tree.

How do I get the transcluded content to re-evaluate within the current state?

**Update**

I think I was barking up the wrong tree. Mathew's answer got me started in the right direction, so it was a big help.

As far as I can tell trying to construct a directive (ng-switch) inside a directive is a bad idea. In the previous plunker when the compile happened the template was changed permanently. That means if I changed the which parameter it wouldn't update. That's what was smelling funny to me in the first place.

Here is a revised plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WUVgdXjwedxO4356321s

In this case, there's a watch on the 'which' value that refires the transclusion. That function removes the previous entry (if any) and adds the new one. There's a couple added benefits.

First I removed the 'item' directive. There's no reason for it to exist, since I'm just looking at the class. Second, I used $animator to do the list manipulation. That means you can add ng-animate to the picker and get animation effects.

I hope that helps someone else looking at this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems with your code:

1) Your template had which being evaluated so your on was becoming the number 1, instead of the variable you wanted which is "which":

```
template: '<div><div ng-switch on="which"></div></div>',
```

2) When you used compile, you needed to pass in the $scope like so:

```
$compile(sel)($scope);
```

Here's an updated plnkr for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6ViJBvkLwQRgUKYMfS9?p=preview

Comment: I had set the incoming which variable to a constant, just to simplify the test case. I wanted to make sure the scope binding wasn't the problem.

The real problem, that you identified, was leaving the $scope off the $compile. That was the key bit I was missing. Thanks!